# How can I write this as a double sum?

Tags: summation

I'm confused about this notation, can someone please explain how I can write

$2 \sum_{1\leq j < k \leq N} P(F_j F_k)$ as a double sum. Would it be $\sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{k=n}^N P(F_j F_k)$?

Also I am just confused about what a double sum would actually mean, I understand that you would sum over the values twice but can someone please explain more in detail? Thank you

Comment: Where does $n$ come from?

Comment: Does $P(F_j F_k)$ have any special meaning?  Generally Readers can only assume it is a term that depends on $j,k$ in a symmetric fashion, i.e. because $F_jF_k=F_kF_j$.  But already in the first summation you've restricted the terms so that $j\lt k$, eliminating any cases $j=k$ and raising a suspicion about why the factor $2$ appears in front of that summation, but not in front of your attempt to rewrite it as a double sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double sum is a sum of the form $$\sum_{j=a}^b \sum_{k=c(j)}^{d(j)} f(j,k) = \sum_{j=a}^b \left(\sum_{k=c(j)}^{d(j)} f(j,k)\right)$$
I used the notation $c(j),d(j)$ because $c$ and $d$ may very well depend on $j$, but they don't have to.

There are more ways you can approach this.

1. We want one variable, say $j$, to be independent, and let it independently take all the values it can possibly have that satisfy the condition $1\le j < k \le N$. We will then adjust $k$ so that this condition is actually met.
   Therefore, let $j$ vary across all values that it can possibly have. These are $1\le j \le N-1$, hence the $\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}$ symbol. Then, let $k$ take all values such that the condition $j < k \le N$. A different way to write this inequality is $j+1 \le k \le N$. Hence, your sum is equal to
   $$2\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^N P(F_jF_k)$$
   To expand this sum, first write out all terms of the inner sum, and then add them up according to the outer sum, like
   $$2\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} (P(F_jF_{j+1})+P(F_jF_{j+2})+...+P(F_jF_N)) =$$
   $$= 2[(P(F_1F_2)+P(F_1F_3)+...+P(F_1F_N)) +$$
   $$+(P(F_2F_3)+P(F_2F_4)+...+P(F_2F_N))+...+$$
   $$+P(F_{N-1}F_N)]$$
   Notice that each successive term of the outer sum has less and less terms of the inner sum (the last one has only one term).
2. Let $k$ vary across all values that it can possibly have. These are $2\le k \le N$. Then, let $j$ take all values such that the condition $1\le j < k$ is met. A different way to write this inequality is $1 \le j \le k-1$. Hence, your sum is equal to
   $$2\sum_{k=2}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} P(F_jF_k)$$

The difference between these two approaches is which variable you assign "independence" to.

Comment: thank you! i have a really stupid question but how come certain double sums have a 2 next to it and other double sums do not?

Comment: also, why do you initially take j to be $1 \leq j \leq N-1$

Comment: And just one more question (sorry!), what exactly does this double sum expand to? like if i had actual numbers/values, then how would this expand?

Comment: @user477465 The 2 is there because your starting sum is multiplied by 2. Maybe the 2 was a typo on your part? As for why I take $1\le j \le N-1$... If you have $1\le j < k \le N$ in the sum, this means that the sum contains all possible combinations of $j$ and $k$ that satisfy this. You can see that $j$ can take the smallest value 1, and $j$ can take the value $N-1$, but it can't take $N$ because then $k$ would have to be $>N$. Of course, $N=1$ is a special case, where no $j,k$ satisfy the condition of the sum, hence the sum is 0. Also, see my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^N P(F_j,F_k)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with something more general:
Assume, that for some finite set $I$, you have a sum
$$
\sum_{l \in I} s_i
$$
Now, the summands correspond to the elements in $I$. If, for some set $J$, we have a bijection

$$
I \overset{\sigma}{\longrightarrow} \bigcup_{j \in J}I_j =: Y
$$
where $I_j \cap I_i = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$, then

$$
\sum_{i\in I} s_i = \sum_{y \in Y} s_{\sigma^{-1}(y)} =
\sum_{y \in \bigcup_{j \in J}I_j} s_{\sigma^{-1}(y)} =
\sum_{j \in J}\sum_{y \in I_j} s_{\sigma^{-1}(y)}
$$
The first equation holds because $\sigma$ is a permutation and addition is commutative. The second equation is trivial and the third equation uses that the union is disjoint, as mentioned above.

So, any bijection $\sigma$ into a disjoint union as mentioned above will give you a representation as a double sum. You could of course proceed inductively, to get triple, quadruple sums et cetera.
The double sum can hence be understood as a specific grouping of summands/a partition of the index set.

Concerning your special case:
Defining $I:=\left\{\left(j,k\right);\,1\leq j < k \leq N\right\}$, you can write
$$
I = \bigcup_{1 \leq j < N} \underbrace{\left\{(j,k);\, j < k \leq N\right\}}_{:= I_j}
$$
and the union is disjoint. Taking $\sigma$ as the identity, and using the above, we get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
& 2 \sum_{(j,k) \in I} P(F_j F_k) =
2 \sum_{(j,k) \in \bigcup_{1 \leq j < N} I_j} P(F_j F_k) = 
2 \sum_{1 \leq j < N} \sum_{(j,k) \in I_j} P(F_j F_k) = \\
& 2 \sum_{1 \leq j < N}\; \sum_{(j,k) \in \left\{(j,m);\, j < m \leq N \right\}} P(F_j F_k) = 2 \sum_{1 \leq j < N} \sum_{j < k \leq N} P(F_j F_k) \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where in the last equation, we used that the sets
$
\left\{(j,m);\, j < m \leq N\right\}
$
and
$
\left\{m;\, j < m \leq N\right\}
$
are bijective/have the same number of elements. There is some subtle formal detail involved in this last equation:

We are basically applying what we used before - $\sum_{i\in I} s_i = \sum_{y \in Y} s_{\sigma_j^{-1}(y)}$ - to the inner sum, where for each $j$, $\sigma_j: \left\{(j,m);\, j < m \leq N\right\} \longrightarrow \left\{m;\, j < m \leq N\right\},\; (j,m) \mapsto m$ is the projection to the second component and $\sigma_j^{-1}$ is the function that maps $m \mapsto (j,m)$.

Explicitly,
$$
\begin{array}
& 2 \sum_{1 \leq j < N}\; \sum_{(j,k) \in \left\{(j,m);\, j < m \leq N \right\}} P(F_j F_k) =
2 \sum_{1 \leq j < N}\; \sum_{(j,k) \in \left\{(j,m);\, j < m \leq N \right\}} P(F_j F_{\sigma_j(j,k)}) = \\
 2 \sum_{1 \leq j < N} \sum_{j < k \leq N} P(F_j F_{\sigma_j(\sigma_j^{-1}(k))}) =
2 \sum_{1 \leq j < N} \sum_{j < k \leq N} P(F_j F_k) \\
\end{array}
$$